# Should I create a linking table between two tables with existing IDs or add a column to an existing table

Tags: foreign-key, primary-key, relations

So I have two tables. Not with these exact columns but it's just to illustrate the point

**users**

```
id | forename | surname
```

**forms**

```
id | name
```

Using MS SQL and was wondering what's best practice to link a user to many forms?

Would it be to create a table as follows:

**users_forms**

```
user_id | form_id
```

Alternatively would it be better adding a new column to the forms table so it was as follows:

**forms**

```
id | name | user_id
```

Does it depend on other factors? if so, which?

Comment: Depends if a form can have many users also. If so then you need another table `FormUser (form_id, user_id, PRIMARY KEY (form_id, user_id))` Otherwise use a single extra column

Comment: if each `form_id` is unique and can be associated to only one user then I would prefer later option which is adding `user_id` to forms.